# More problems with the "easy to learn" angularjs framework

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do the simplest thing which AngularJS obviously makes incredibly difficult.

This code here works:

```
.factory('ItemService', [function() {
var items = [
  {id: 1, label: 'Item 0'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Item 1'}
];
return {
  list: function() {
    return items;
  },
  add: function(item) {
    items.push(item);
  }
};
```

The variable items is declared at the top of the factory and is accessible in the return statement.

So why doesn't this work:

```
.factory('ItemService', ['$http', function($http) {
var self = this;
self.items = [];
$http.get('/api_job_inspections/1/edit').then(function(response) {
    //self.items = response.data;
    self.items = [
        {id: 1, label: 'Item 0'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Item 1'}
      ];
  }, function(errResponse) {
    console.error('Error while fetching notes');
  });



return {
  list: function() {
    return self.items;
  },
  add: function(item) {
    self.items.push(item);
  }
};
```

I have tried using var items = [] like in the first example but nothing gets returned. Using this syntax nothing gets returned. Why? There seems to be a scoping issue but what is it?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: When are you expecting something to be returned?

Comment: Use service instead of factory if you want to use this

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like a scoping issue, but rather an async issue, did you make sure the ajax call is complete?

Try in your controller doing the following:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ItemsController', 
       ['ItemService', '$scope', function(items, $scope) {
            $scope.$watch(function() {
                 return items.list();
                 }, function(newVal) {
                      console.log(newVal);
                   });
        }]);
```

p.s. Instead of using factory you can use service, it's a wrapper around factory, which will basically allow you to use `this.something = function` it's a lot more convenient than factory (imo).

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `items` is available before the function returns, whereas in the second example you are making an asynchronous call. `self.items` is simply not yet populated by the time your service is injected into your controller.

Both examples are fundamentally different and thus require a different API exposed to the consumer of the service (i.e. the controller).

You should consider adding a `loadItems` function to your service:

```
...
loadItems: function(){

   return $http.get('/api_job_inspections/1/edit')
            .then(function(response){
                    self.items = response.data;
                    return self.items;
                  }, 
                  function(errResponse) {
                     console.error('Error while fetching notes');
                  });
},
...
```

In the controller you can then do:

```
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, ItemService){
   ItemService.loadItems()
      .then(function(items)){
         $scope.items = items;
         // ItemService.list will also be available, so you can do:
         // $scope.items = ItemService.list;
      }
})
```

This is not related to using `.factory` vs. `.service` as was suggested.

Also, there is no need to create a deferred object with `$q.defer` - `$http` already returns a `.then`-able promise.

Answer (score 1):

It's an async issue. You can use `$q`:

```
app.factory('ItemService', ['$http', '$q',
  function($http, $q) {
    var self = this;
    var service = {};
    self.items = [];
    service.list = function(callback) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var cb=callback||angular.noop;
      $http.get('/api_job_inspections/1/edit').success(function(data) {
        //self.items = data;
        self.items = [{
          id: 1,
          label: 'Item 0'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Item 1'
        }];
        deferred.resolve(self.items);
        return cb();
      }).error(function(err) {
        console.error('Error while fetching notes');
        deferred.reject(err);
        return cb(err);
      }.bind(this));
      return deferred.promise;
    };
    service.add=function(item){
      self.items.push(item);
    };
    return service;
  }
]);
```

Then in your controller you can use this service like this:

```
ItemService.list().then(function(data){
    $scope.items=data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will mark as the right answer.

Comment: @s.alem, there is no need to create a deferred object. `$http` already returns a promise